# how to add foriegnkey object and connnect it a post object through a single endpoint in Django rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class PostAdvertisment(models.Model):
    # post=models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    url=models.URLField(null=True,blank=True)
    advertizing_content= models.TextField(null =True ,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'
class Post(models.Model):

    # created_at=models.DateTimeField(efault=datetime.now, blank=True)

    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="post")
    title=models.CharField(max_length=128,null=True,blank=True)
    rate=models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(5)],default=True,null=True,blank=True)

    # rating=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    content=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    review=models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    url=models.URLField(null=True,blank=True)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True,related_name="post_voters")
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    comments=models.ManyToManyField('Comment',blank=True,related_name="comments_post")
    anonymous = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    fake = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    genuine = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , blank=True, related_name="post_genuines")
    spam = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , blank=True, related_name="post_spames")
    advertisement=models.ForeignKey(PostAdvertisment,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.content}'
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:post_detail' , kwargs={'post_id':Post.id})
```

so here is my serializers.py

```
class PostSerializer(TaggitSerializer,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
    author = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, required=False, read_only=True)
    # title = serializers.CharField()

    advertisement = PostAdvertisementSerializer()
    # advertisement = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    #     queryset=PostAdvertisment.objects.all(),   
    #     slug_field='advertisement'
    #      )
    # category_name = serializers.CharField(source='advertisement.title')
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','title','rate','author','content','review','url','tags', 'fake','comments', 'created_at', 'anonymous','advertisement')
    # def create(self, validated_data):
    #     tag = validated_data.pop('advertisement')
    #     tag_instance, created =PostAdvertisment.objects.get_or_create(title=tag)
    #     article_instance = Post.objects.create(**validated_data, advertisement=tag_instance)
    #     return article_instance 
    # def create(self, validated_data):
    #     serializer = self.get_serializer(data=self.request.data)
    #     advertisment =  self.request.data.pop('advertisement')
    #     company_instance = PostAdvertisment.objects.filter(id=advertisment).first()
    #     if not serializer.is_valid():
    #         print(serializer.errors)
    #     data = serializer.validated_data
    #     serializer.save(PostAdvertisment=company_instance)
    #     headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    #     return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers) 
    def create(self,validated_data):
        advertisement=validated_data.pop('advertisement')


        post=  Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for advertise in advertisement:
            PostAdvertisment.object.create(**advertise)
        return post
```

so the commented part of the code is something which  I've Tried 
differnt appraoches gave me differnt kidn of error but none of them have worked

```
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers
```

I've followeed this 
but its no use when ever i try to post an object either that advertisment might be null or it gives me some kind of strange error depening  on the create method i have used

```
"advertisement":[]
this is what the error 

{
    "advertisement": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
        ]
    }
}
```

when i changed it to `{}`

```
"advertisement": null
```

but when i tried to give data to it

```
AttributeError at /api/post/
type object 'PostAdvertisment' has no attribute 'object'

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/post/
```

im not sure how to add data to nested objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missprinted, not PostAdvertisment.object.create(**advertise) but PostAdvertisment.objects.create(**advertise) you missed "s".
Advice you to read the error(traceback).

Comment: yeah sorted,
but i just want to know another thing 
the postadvertisment object is being created but  that isnt being added to Post Object 
i mean the value is tstill null

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think the advertisement is expected to be a list. Based on the `Post` model and `PostSerializer`, advertisement is only one.

After creating a `PostAdvertisement` you also have to update `post.advertisement`/`post.advertisement_id`. This is how I think it would be:

```
advertisement=validated_data.pop('advertisement')
post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
post.advertisement = PostAdvertisment.objects.create(**advertisement)
post.save()
return post
```

You could also create the `PostAdvertisement` first then create the `Post` so there is only 2 db queries instead of 3:

```
validated_data["advertisement"] = PostAdvertisment.objects.create(**validated_data["advertisement"])
post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
return post
```